# Map EC2 instance ID to hostname to deregister instance from monitoring system

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I am trying to **remove monitoring of EC2 instances** whenever they are being terminated from an Auto Scaling Group.

1. Created CloudWatch Rule whenever Autoscaling termination is true >> Call Lambda function which is calling system manager to execute monitoring Deregister shell script.
2. Once De-register script run on the instance it sends out the details which includes hostname, IP, Customer code.
3. Once my monitoring relay server gets that file it de-register the instance.
4. During this whole process Autoscaling lifecycle hook holds the instance for 60 min.

This whole process is working however, it is too much to configure. What I want is to map the CloudWatch terminate event with my Monitoring server so that whenever any termination happens that instance gets removed from monitoring.

The problem I am facing is that my monitoring system only understands Hostname and CloudWatch captures instance ID.

Comment: How is your **Hostname** being set? Is it being set by your application, or is AWS setting it to a default value? How is it normally accessible?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method would be to activate the Auto Scaling notification that can send an event to Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS) when Auto Scaling terminates an instance.

See: [Getting SNS Notifications When Your Auto Scaling Group Scales](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/ASGettingNotifications.html)

Specifically, the event is `autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE`.

You can then **subscribe to the SNS Topic** and receive a message such as this:

```
Service: AWS Auto Scaling
Time: 2017-03-26T07:57:08.768Z
RequestId: 89c49e5c-2bbd-44fb-984e-5bda05291313
Event: autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATE
AccountId: 123456789012
AutoScalingGroupName: ASG
AutoScalingGroupARN: arn:aws:autoscaling:ap-southeast-2:123456789012:autoScalingGroup:5d65418d-e5a0-4a5a-a030-f4273a8a15a8:autoScalingGroupName/ASG
ActivityId: 89c49e5c-2bbd-44fb-984e-5bda05291313
Description: Terminating EC2 instance: i-046b4f0de355b0dff
Cause: At 2017-03-26T07:56:17Z a user request update of AutoScalingGroup constraints to min: 1, max: 2, desired: 1 changing the desired capacity from 2 to 1. At 2017-03-26T07:56:26Z an instance was taken out of service in response to a difference between desired and actual capacity, shrinking the capacity from 2 to 1. At 2017-03-26T07:56:26Z instance i-046b4f0de355b0dff was selected for termination.
StartTime: 2017-03-26T07:56:26.662Z
EndTime: 2017-03-26T07:57:08.768Z
StatusCode: InProgress
StatusMessage: 
Progress: 50
EC2InstanceId: i-046b4f0de355b0dff
Details: {"Subnet ID":"subnet-7c087015","Availability Zone":"ap-southeast-2a"}
```

You also mention that you need the **Hostname**. This, of course, depends upon where you configure the Hostname. If it is set by your application, then one option would be:

- Also add the Hostname to a tag on the instance (this can be done at startup or whenever you normally set the Hostname)
- When responding to the Termination notification from SNS, call the `DescribeInstances` command to retrieve the tag from the instance and pass it to your monitoring system